# Access Azure Table Storage in SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm trying to access Azure Table Storage in a Gen 2 data lake from Azure SQL Server, but I can't find any documentation. Loads on how to get to csv's in blob storage, but nothing on Azure tables.

Any ideas?
John

Answer (score 0):

**Your requirement isn't feasible.**

> Azure Table storage is a service that stores **non-relational
> structured data** (also known as structured NoSQL data) in the cloud,
> providing a key/attribute store with a **schemaless design**.

Since, Table storage can't be queried using SQL, therefore there is no sense to access it using any SQL Server.

I recommend you to first go through [Table storage concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview#table-storage-concepts)
 before knowing how to query it.

Once getting the Table Storage structure, you can query the tables either through **REST API** or **Cosmos DB Table API** based on your application. Refer [Querying tables and entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities).

You can also follow this complete tutorial [Quickstart: Build a Table API app with .NET SDK and Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/create-table-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cvisual-studio#create-a-database-account) to create basic application using Table Storage for learning purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I can't find any docs on using an API directly in an SQL query. I can access and query the data using online tools with odata queries, that's well understood. To clarify then : 'How do I send an odata query to an azure table from azure sql?' If it's rest API are there any docs you know of, or is it just a plain 'No'

Comment: You can't use API in SQL query. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api. REST API is the standard way to query Table storage.